# How to apply Git commits of a forked branch without the merges?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-fork

I've forked a Git repo, and I've been committing on it for a while.
During this time, I merged my fork with another branches, and again made commits...
I would like to apply all my changes on another repo, without including **my** merges.

How can I do that?

Comment: `cherry-pick`? `format-patch` with `am`? `rebase`? There's really not enough information here to suggest the best route.

Comment: cherry pick will be applied to only one commit,will format patch be able to filter by an author? what am does? rebase won't delete other's merges.

Comment: `cherry-pick` can be used on multiple commits - e.g. `git cherry-pick master..otherbranch` will copy all commits from `otherbranch` since it's most recent diversion from `master` onto your current branch. `git am` is the counterpart to `git format-patch` and applies the patches created by it. Filtering will have to be done manually, or by running a `git filter-branch` after copying all the commits you want.

Comment: okay, how do I filter all the commits made by me, and apply them to another repo without picking them manually but by their author?(I used my email to commit).